# Issue while accessing XMLTYPE column via DB LINK

Tags: oracle, xmltype

My database is `Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production`.

We are trying to access a table via DBLINK with XMLTYPE column in `Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production`.

While accessing, we can do a simple count(1) on the table and get the output however if we try to query the XMLTYPE column we are getting the following error.

> ORA-03001: unimplemented feature
> ORA-02063: preceding line from R22_VISIONBI
> 03001. 00000 -  "unimplemented feature"
> *Cause:    This feature is not implemented.
> *Action:   None.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't an Oracle XMLType be sent over a DBLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752284/why-cant-an-oracle-xmltype-be-sent-over-a-dblink)