# DELETE FROM throws a SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn=5159) on a query, on which a SELECT works

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, subquery, sql-delete

Trying to delete a specific amount of rows in a MySQL query, I am able to `SELECT` whatever I want to delete with the following command, getting the results I need:

```
select * from ns_cos ns where ns.created_at <>
    (select max(nsa.created_at) from ns_cos nsa
        where nsa.month_year = ns.month_year)
```

**However**, when I try to delete the selected data with:

```
delete from ns_cos ns where ns.created_at not exists
    (select max(nsa.created_at) from ns_cos nsa
        where nsa.month_year = ns.month_year)
```

I get:

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn=5159) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ns where ns.created_at not exists (select max(nsa.created_at) from ns_cos nsa wh' at line 1

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your immediate issue is that not all MySQL versions support aliasing the table directly in `delete from`. Furthermore, though, you cannot re-open the table you delete `from` in the `from` clause.

Consider using the `delete ... join` syntax.

```
delete ns
from ns_cos ns
inner join (
    select month_year, max(nsa.created_at) created_at
    from ns_cos nsa 
    group by month_year
) ns1 on ns1.month_year = ns.month_year and ns1.created_at <> ns.created_at
```

Answer (score 1):

EXISTS in there not posible use IN clause, but you need to enclose  the table in a seprate select, so that mysql thinks it is another table

```
delete from ns_cos ns 
where ns.created_at not IN (select max(nsa.created_at) from (SELECT * FROM ns_cos) nsa where nsa.month_year = ns.month_year)
```

Comment: Error: *You can't specify target table 'ns' for update in FROM clause* - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0bd7fbc06b98687aa0489bacf265618d

Comment: Somehow it did not work, gave the standard errors I was getting before. Still, 10x for the efforts :)

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you join tables from two schemas, no matter whether you take aliases for the table names or not.

##### Error

SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '...'

##### delete !ALIAS! from table ALIAS ...

Strangely, *only* with aliases, you can get around this error in a one-step SQL. Tested in MySQL 5.7.

Try this pattern, using the alias of the table you want to delete from between `delete` and `from`:

```sql
delete t1 from table t1
join table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id
```

Your code would be:

```sql
delete ns from ns_cos ns where ns.created_at not exists
    (select max(nsa.created_at) from ns_cos nsa
        where nsa.month_year = ns.month_year)
```

##### Other steps I checked before finding out the alias trick (do not read)

- I tried it with a view of the other schema's table in the same schema, that is not enough.
- One way to get around this is to make a copy of the table in the same schema (and delete that copy afterwards).
- You might also somehow make a full "linked server link" like in T-SQL `[linkedservername].DB1.Schema.Table1` at [How to join two tables if they are in different schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5813760/11154841) Your code is on the same server, but this might still help jumping over to the other schema, untested.