# Query Two Tables from different Schema but Same Database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

First, I saw a similar question asked here:[Query two tables from different schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980620/query-two-tables-from-different-schema), but the answer did not work for me.

My Situation: same table, different schemas, same database (oracle by the way). I am trying to find all rows in one schema.table that are not in the other. I have the following query:

```
select S1.ID
FROM SCHEMA1.DATABASE_UPDATE S1, 
SCHEMA2.DATABASE_UPDATE S2
WHERE
S1.ID != S2.ID
```

I get thousands of repeating entries. So obviously, this is wrong. There are 448 rows in S1 and 439 in S2. There should be only 9 unique rows. What am I doing wrong? thanks!

By the way, I am doing this from sqlDeveloper.

Answer (score 3):

The minus is a good solution but I recommand to do in differente side.

```
select S1.ID
FROM SCHEMA1.DATABASE_UPDATE S1
minus
select S2.ID
SCHEMA2.DATABASE_UPDATE S2
```

and

```
select S2.ID
SCHEMA2.DATABASE_UPDATE S2    
minus
select S1.ID
FROM SCHEMA1.DATABASE_UPDATE S1
```

the other way to do that (in one query):

```
select S1.ID,S2.ID
FROM SCHEMA1.DATABASE_UPDATE S1
FULL OUTER JOIN SCHEMA2.DATABASE_UPDATE S2 ON (S1.ID = S2.ID)
WHERES S1.ID IS NULL OR S2.ID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

many ways to get the difference between two tables, the easiest of which is MINUS

```
select S1.ID FROM SCHEMA1.DATABASE_UPDATE S1, 
MINUS
select S2.ID FROM SCHEMA2.DATABASE_UPDATE S2
```

Your solution creates a cross-product where every row in S1 is matched to every row in S2 where the s2.id is different than the S1.ID - which is most of them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the proper grant select on the the related schema owners

if  you need   all the  rows in one schema.table that are not in the other you can use minus  eg:

```
select S1.ID
FROM SCHEMA1.DATABASE_UPDATE S1
minus
select S2.ID
SCHEMA2.DATABASE_UPDATE S2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting all the pairs of rows from the two schemas, where the ID in the first is different from the ID in the second. What you do want, in fact, is the ID's in one table that are not among the ID's in the second. That's a different question.

There was an old, long-going discussion on AskTom about the most efficient way to do this some time ago. If I recall, it turns out that the most efficient way is to `UNION ALL` the two tables (or just the ID from the two tables, if that is all you need), `GROUP BY ID` and retain only those `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`. (Assuming, that is, that `ID` is the primary key in the two tables.)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?  Left join then filter to the results that didn't return a result in the second table.  Then if necessary you could use a UNION to return the opposite result as well.

```
SELECT S1.ID 
FROM SCHEMA1.DATABASE_UPDATE S1
LEFT JOIN SCHEMA2.DATABASE_UPDATE S2
WHERE S2.ID IS NULL
```