# execute immediate over database link

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Is it possible to execute dynamic PL/SQL on a remote database via a databse link?

I'm looking for something like:

```
l_stmt := 'begin null; end;';
execute immediate l_stmt@dblink;
```

The syntax above is obviously wrong, I get **PLS-00201: identifier 'L_STMT@DBLINK' must be declared**.

It is possible to create a procedure remotely and then execute it. Is there a way to execute code without creating a remote procedure?

EDIT:
I'm trying to work around passing a type over DB link. A remote procedure requires a parameter of type t_id_tab which is defined on the remote DB as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_ID_TAB AS TABLE OF NUMBER(12)
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can execute arbitary code on the remote database by calling the DBMS_SQL package there.

Sample:

```
set serveroutput on

create or replace synonym remote_dbms_sql for dbms_sql@core;

declare
  c  number;
  l_global_name  varchar2(200);
begin
  c := remote_dbms_sql.open_cursor();
  remote_dbms_sql.parse( c, 'select global_name from global_name', dbms_sql.native );
  remote_dbms_sql.define_column( c, 1, l_global_name, 200 );
  dbms_output.put_line( remote_dbms_sql.execute_and_fetch( c ) );
  remote_dbms_sql.column_value( c, 1, l_global_name );
  dbms_output.put_line( l_global_name );
  remote_dbms_sql.close_cursor( c );
end;
/
```

Note that the reference to DBMS_SQL.NATIVE is local, not remote.  You can't reference remote package constants, but presumably the actual value of this constant is the same in both databases.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you would just qualify the object names in the procedure, rather than qualifying the procedure itself.

Comment: that's what I thought. Unfortunately I have to use remote types in the stmt, which does not seem to work without hacking both DBs like described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378299/referencing-oracle-user-defined-types-over-dblink

Answer (score 0):

You are missing execute in above example. Please see below:

```
ret := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(c);
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to create the array on a package instead of a type? I mean:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE the_package AS
  TYPE T_ID_TAB AS TABLE OF NUMBER(12);
END the_package;
```

May be, with this way works, I've not tried...

Comment: Unfortunately I have to call the procedure on the remote DB that takes T_ID_TAB@DBLINK as parameter, that is the SQL type as opposed to the PL/SQL array.