# calling a stored proc over a dblink

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, ora-24338

I am trying to call a stored procedure over a database link. The code looks something like this:

```
declare
       symbol_cursor  package_name.record_cursor;
       symbol_record  package_name.record_name;
begin
       symbol_cursor := package_name.function_name('argument');
loop
       fetch symbol_cursor into symbol_record;
       exit when symbol_cursor%notfound;
       -- Do something with each record here, e.g.:
       dbms_output.put_line( symbol_record.field_a );
end loop;

CLOSE symbol_cursor;
```

When I run this from the same DB instance and schema where package_name belongs to I am able to run it fine. However, when I run this over a database link, (with the required modification to the stored proc name, etc) I get an oracle error: ORA-24338: statement handle not executed.

The modified version of this code over a dblink looks like this:

```
declare
       symbol_cursor  package_name.record_cursor@db_link_name;
       symbol_record  package_name.record_name@db_link_name;
begin
       symbol_cursor := package_name.function_name@db_link_name('argument');
loop
       fetch symbol_cursor into symbol_record;
       exit when symbol_cursor%notfound;
       -- Do something with each record here, e.g.:
       dbms_output.put_line( symbol_record.field_a );
end loop;

CLOSE symbol_cursor;
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119306/execute-immediate-over-databse-link

Comment: I don't agree that this is a duplicate of that question, which is about executing *dynamic* code over a dblink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From another of your questions I remember package_name.record_cursor to be a ref cursor type. A ref cursor is a memory handle only valid in the database it was created in. In other words, you cannot create a ref cursor in your remote db and try to fetch from it your local db.

If you really need to process the data in your local db and the tables have to stay in the remote db, then you could move the package "package_name" into your local db and have it execute the query on tables in your remote db via a database link.

Comment: that makes sense to me. However (pardon my ignorance), how do ref cursors work when returned over a jdbc link? Isn't it used in a different memory space in that case as well? thanks.

Comment: An application accesses a data base over a jdbc connection. Your application can indeed get a ref cursor from a stored procedure. But you would not use that ref cursor locally/application side. Instead, you would hand the ref cursor back to the database for fetch operations. You basically tell the database "give me the result set associated with this handle here".