# Oracle SQL Query takes too long in JdbcTemplate & SimpleJdbcTemplate

Tags: sql, oracle, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

The oracle SQL query available in our application that uses a SimpleJdbcTemplate never (almost) comes out. The query is very long that connects nearly 15 tables, selects approximately 100 fields and so on.

The query is nearly 8500 characters, 6 bind variables added to it using MapSqlParameterSource instance). I have put enough log messages in the Row Mapper method calls, though the messages are never printed.

The same SQL query after replacing the bind variables with actual values produces the result in 5-7 seconds in SQL*Plus & SQL Developer. The result is only 15 records since I use the logic to implement the pagination support in SQL query itself.

I tried both JDBCTemplate & SimpleJdbcTemplate. 
Any Idea what could be going wrong??

**UPDATE ::**

I was able to narrow down the issue. My query contained one synonym as a LEFT OUTER JOIN (which referred to a different schema table) was slowing down the entire query. This was happening when I used this join along with bind variables. When I hard coded the values for bind variables in SQL Developer & SQL*Plus, query was running fine. But when I used the bind variables the same thing (hanging situation) happened in those tools as well.

Currently I am referring to the following link to correct my dblink/synonym usage,
[Getting a ResultSet/RefCursor over a database link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549417/getting-a-resultset-refcursor-over-a-database-link)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you have a different performance between two different connect methods make sure that they don't alter the session optimizer setting.

Maybe your jdbc code somehow specifies the optmizer mode and thus is different form when you connect via sqlplus.

```
alter session set OPTIMIZER_MODE = RULE;
alter session set OPTIMIZER_MODE = choose;
```

I had such a problem as well in our environment, so I made sure that all connections use the same optimiziation setting.

Comment: There is no specific JDBC configuration parameters I used while creating the connection. I finished testing the same SQL with simple JDBC Connection (Without DataSource/Spring) using DriverManager.createConnection call.. The same behavior is repeated for this connection as well. I tried both the optimizer modes in the same connection, and repeated the execution of the SQL statement. But no luck!!

Comment: If you have the permissions you can run "select value from v$parameter where name='optimizer_mode';" to see if both your sessions have the same setting. If you don't have the permissions you can still set the optimizer mode manually in sql developer by using the alter statement. If the query runs fast with the selected mode, then use the same alter statement in your JDBC connection and see if it is still performs slow.

Comment: Also you can try to use hints in the statement. Maybe oracle uses different execution plans for the statements.

Comment: optimizer mode in all options printed was all_rows (which is a cost based optimizer), and all my tables are analyzed ones. Don't think it as a performance issue on DB side, even with the misleading query hints the query finishes under 1 minute in Oracle tools, whereas JDBC Connection result has never came after 3 hours...!!

Comment: If you think it is a problem in the JDBC connection, have you tried to do "select * from dual;" and see if this also returns slow?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that in JDBC - I get results for smaller queries. The only query I don't get result is this long query, and for this query I get result from other places..

Comment: I have updated the case history with the details identified. Thanks