# Strongly Defined Cursor Output of Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am currently trying to use an Oracle PL/SQL procedure written by someone else in a function I am writing. It takes strongly defined cursor as an IN OUT argument. The procedure opens the cursor and does a select on it. I need to access the data that the cursor is pointing to after the procedure is called. The cursor is typed as a record also defined by the user.

I have a function where I declare a system reference cursor and pass that cursor as the IN OUT argument for the procedure. After calling the procedure I try to fetch the data from the reference cursor I declared. I copied the definition of the record type to my function and tried to fetch the data from the cursor into a record of that type.

The function compiles, but when I go to run it I get the error "ORA-24338: Statement Handle Not Executed". I looked up this error and it seems it occurs when you try and fetch from a cursor that hasn't been opened. I looked through the procedure and there are no conditional statements or returns before the open statement that would stop the procedure from reaching the open, therefore the open should be reached for every call to the procedure.

I figured it has something to do with the fact that the procedure defined its IN OUT as a user defined type but I defined the cursor I pass into the procedure in my function as a system reference cursor. I tried copying the type definition from the procedure into my function and declaring the reference cursor in my function as that type, but then I get a compile error that says I am passing in arguments of the wrong type to the procedure.

I apologize as I am not able to include any of the code, but I figured I would write out my logic in detail and hopefully someone would be able to confirm whether my logic is right or wrong, as I am pretty sure it is an issue with my reference cursor logic. Thank you.

**edit**

I'll try and create a generic example code that demonstrates the problem

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function schemaName.functionName
(
  paramDeclaration TYPE
  ...
  paramDeclaration TYPE
) RETURN TYPE

IS 

return_record record_type@otherDatabase;
myCursor cursor@otherDatabase;

BEGIN

procedure@otherDatabase(myCursor);

LOOP
   FETCH myCursor INTO return_record;
EXIT WHEN myCursor%NOTFOUND
```

NOTE: procedure@otherDatabase is where myCursor is opened with a select statement.

Hopefully that helps. Again, I apologize for not being able to provide more information.

Comment: I probably should also mention that my function where I call the procedure is on a different database that the procedure. Would opening a reference cursor in a procedure on a different database cause this issue?

Comment: We understand that you may not be able to include the actual code that you're using.  But surely you can create a sample piece of code that doesn't reference any of your objects but does reproduce the problem you're seeing.  Otherwise, we'd have to ask a bunch of questions to try to clarify how things are defined.  If there are multiple databases and database links involved (rather than just different schemas which are what other RDBMS products refer to as databases), that only makes sample code more important.

Comment: why can't you include the code?

Comment: I made an edit to my original post including some generic code that duplicates the conditions causing my problem

Comment: You haven't shown how the cursor is defined, but if it's a ref type then possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1122175/266304). (You aren't using a sys_refcursor as stated in the question though; when you do, do you get an empty result set instead of an error?)

Comment: @Alex sorry about that, i've been working on it and made some changes. myCursor cursor@otherDatabase; is the definition where the cursor type is defined in otherDatabase as a refrence cursor that returns the record_type that my record was defined as. 

the code would be:
Type cursor IS REF CURSOR RETURN record_type 

if I instead define the cursor as myCursor SYS_REFCURSOR I get the same problem as what I get with the code I provided. the problem being that it compiles, but when I try to call the function I get an "ORA_24338: Statment Handle Not Executed" error, as if the cursor wasneveropened

Comment: The problem alex linked answers my question. It is because my function is on a different database than the procedure that opens the cursor. 

Thanks everyone for the help, and I apologize for the insufficient information at the start. I know how frustrating that can be when trying to help someone. I'll keep the tip on providing generic code that replicates the problem conditions in mind for the next time I ask a question. 

Hey Alex, could you post your comment as the answer so I can accept it and close the question? Thanks.

Comment: @Nickknack - right, then it is a duplicate, and you can't do that as far as I'm aware. You can't define a local type and use that - Oracle sees them as different types even if they look the same to you, so you'd get PLS-00306 or similar.

Comment: @Nickknack - looks like [you can actually do this with `dbms_sql`](https://community.oracle.com/message/12640183); quite how depends on your version. Ran out of time to put a demo together...