# execute a variable using database link

Tags: oracle

I have this query:

```
DECLARE VAR1 VARCHAR(100);
BEGIN
    VAR1 :='INSERT INTO TAB1 (ID) VALUES(911197)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE VAR1;
    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

it will be executed with no errors (the above is simple example, in my real issue, VAR1 will be provided from a procedure)

My problem is in the below issue, I want to execute the VAR1 in another database using database link, its giving me error , what is the correct syntax?.

```
create public database link
    alink
connect to
    stack
identified by
    flow
using 'server'

DECLARE VAR1 VARCHAR(100);
BEGIN
    VAR1 :='INSERT INTO TAB1 (ID) VALUES(911197)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE VAR1@alink;
    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

it will not works , how I will be able the execute the `var1` into another database?

EDIT:

while trying this query , I had the below error :

```
create or replace synonym remote_dbms_sql for dbms_sql@sales;
declare
c  number;
l_global_name  varchar2(200);

begin
c := remote_dbms_sql.open_cursor();
remote_dbms_sql.parse( c,'INSERT INTO ID (CODE) VALUES(911197)', dbms_sql.native );
remote_dbms_sql.define_column( c, 1, l_global_name, 200 );
dbms_output.put_line( remote_dbms_sql.execute_and_fetch( c ) );
remote_dbms_sql.column_value( c, 1, l_global_name );
dbms_output.put_line( l_global_name );
remote_dbms_sql.close_cursor( c );
end;
/


Error:ORA-01007: variable not in select list
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1673
```

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/q/1119306/2711647

Comment: @DurgeshChaudhary It gave me this error ORA-01007: variable not in select list
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1673

Comment: Reason being `You can't reference remote package constants, but presumably the actual value of this constant is the same in both databases.`

Comment: And can you also post the new Code you are trying to execute after you tried said link http://stackoverflow.com/q/1119306/2711647

Comment: sorry I didnt understand at your last comment @DurgeshChaudhary however check with my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be this one:

```
BEGIN
    VAR1 :='INSERT INTO TAB1@alink (ID) VALUES(911197)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE VAR1;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: I cannot use such way because in my real scenario I dont know what is inside the variable . what I am sure they are executable query. I will explain my scenarion in my question

Comment: Is it suitable to create synonym for the tables, e.g. `create or replace synonym remote_tab1 for tab1@sales;`? Of course, you would have to create a synonym for each possible table that may occour inside `VAR1`