# How pass a local UDT to a remote DB function?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to use this PLSQL block:

```
DECLARE 
  V_LOG_ENTRY I_LOG_ENTRY; 
  V_LOG_RETURN INTEGER;
BEGIN 
  V_LOG_ENTRY := I_LOG_ENTRY(arguments...); 
  V_LOG_RETURN := I_SESSION_LOGGING.WRITE_LOG_ENTRY@REMOTE(V_LOG_ENTRY, 0);
END;
```

`WRITE_LOG_ENTRY` is expecting the type I_LOG_ENTRY. This type is present on both the local db and the remote db. They both have the same OID.

When I execute the block, I get the error: `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'WRITE_LOG_ENTRY'`

Signature for `WRITE_LOG_ENTRY`:

```
function WRITE_LOG_ENTRY(
      P_LOG_ENTRY I_LOG_ENTRY, P_current_log_level INTEGER DEFAULT NULL
 )
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you count the number of `arguments` in `I_LOG_ENTRY(arguments...);`?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Yes, updated with function signature

Comment: Duplicate question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378299/referencing-oracle-user-defined-types-over-dblink

Comment: Thanks @kfinity. I am now using a different approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was trying to do is not possible.

Please see [Referencing Oracle user defined types over DBLINK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378299/referencing-oracle-user-defined-types-over-dblink) as suggested by @kfinity for a different approach.